# VBA Code - Need help copying format of one cell across a whole row based on particular cell value or format in column A

Tags: excel, vba, format, range, conditional-formatting

I have this code below that works for updating the format of cells in Column A if the cell starts with "00".

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("A6:A300")
If Left(cel.Value, 2) = "00" Then
cel.Font.Color = vbWhite
cel.Interior.Color = vbBlack
End If
Next
```

What I really want to do is when "00" is encountered in a cell in Column A I want white text and black cell interior not only in the Column A cell but to then copy that same formatting across the row from A:W. For example, if "00" is encountered in A7, then I want this format from A7:W7, and so on. Where "00" appears in Column A is different each time the data source is updated so it needs to be flexible.

I'm hoping there is a simple solution where I can add a second range after the THEN statement. Something like below (which does not work):

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("A6:A300")
If Left(cel.Value, 2) = "00" Then Range("A:W")
cel.Font.Color = vbWhite
cel.Interior.Color = vbBlack
End If
Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row,1),ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row,23)).Font...`

Comment: Wouldn't conditional formatting work here?

Comment: @RichardCrossley it probably could but this report is pulled too often, really need it included in the macro.